# How to make a form in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I don't know much about Excel. But, I want to make a form in Excel. Some items are fillable, and then others will have a drop-down menu for choices that is linked to another page that I can update from time to time. And, then I want the form to output all the items selected and items filled. How should I go about doing this? I hope you could help me. Thanks!

Comment: You should start by doing some research on your own. You are basically asking "How do I do everything" without even trying to find a solution yourself.  You have also tagged this question with "google-form". Where in your question is this relevant?

Comment: I see. I've removed the tag. I just thought that maybe there would be an option in google form that would accomplish this. I've been reading the docs but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Your question is still way to broad. Stackoverflow is where you come for help with some part of your project that you can't find a solution to. Like a part of your code that does not act like you expect it to and you can not figure out why. You are asking how you should do everything in a very vaguely described project. No one can answer this question with the information given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is as good a starting point as any for forms in Excel:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lV9X2K8uEYE

(It's worth continuing down the google forms route though as they provide an excellent interface and Google has already done most of the heavy lifting for you.)

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the link! I finished my excel thingy. I just didn't know the right keywords. I was surprised how simple it is. I really appreciate your help. 